# How to create a html paypal with no Billing information input needed?

Tags: html, paypal

I want to create a html paypal form. But how can I make the form with no Billing information input needed? Or what input variable should I add in the form? So The buyer don't need to input Billing information as the image shown below.

[image: html form]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the buyer to input billing information again in PayPal checkout page, you can pass buyer's billing information form your site to PayPal, as below:

```html
<input type='hidden' name='first_name' value='tet'>
<input type='hidden' name='last_name' value='test'>
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="NE">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="68114">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="US">
<input type='hidden' name='address1' value='testtest'>
```

Then PayPal can fill in these information automatically.